# Ubuntu 18.04 installer is not showing partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, fdisk, gdisk

I have an HP pavilion workstation, that came with windows 10 preinstalled, and I want to make it a dual boot with Linux. The problem is that even after doing all the following:

- Disabled secure boot
- Disabled windows fast start up
- Shrunk the windows C volume as an unallocated space (even created a new separate volume)

I still get no option (partition) in the installer.

I tried viewing the partitions in gparted but only the USB flash in which I have the installation image is shown

I tried `gdisk` and got the following (931 GB correspond to the windows volume, the rest 200 I have no idea what they represent):
[image]

I should also mention that the machine has an M.2 drive too. But even with optane memory disabled, I get the same errors in the ubuntu installer.

Any idea how to fix this, and get ubuntu installed?

Comment: If you carefully read the whole text in your image post, you can see that there are several problem on your disk layout. You use a GPT tool while your disk use MBR. ALso it seems the 2nd partition overlaps the first one. Fix that before installing ubuntu

Comment: how would I do that?